# Splitting Pandas series with regex and word grouping constraints

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

Say I have df as follows:

```py
MyCol
Red Motor
Blue Taxi
Green Taxi-1
Light blue small Taxi-1 
Light blue big Taxi-2
```

I would like to split the color and the vehicle into two columns. I used this command to split the last word (could be any character).

The last word (could be any character, like taxi or taxi-1) refers to the vehicle. Sometimes, there is a 'big' or 'small' associated with the car name. The first few words (can be one or more than one words) refers to the color.

This is what I have tried. It only works when the last word is a word without special characters. How can I include the case when special characters in the last word too?

```
df['MyCol'].str.extract('^(.*?)\s((?:small|big)?\s?\w+).*$')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df['MyCol'].str.extract('^(.*?)\s((?:small|big|)\s?\S+)$')
```

resulting in:

|  | 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Red | Motor |
| 1 | Blue | Taxi |
| 2 | Green | Taxi-1 |
| 3 | Light blue | small Taxi-1 |
| 4 | Light blue | big Taxi |

Comment: may i ask why adding .* doesn't work?

Comment: It is unclear to me what you wanted to capture with ".*" at the end. ".*" is greedy, so it will capture something if it can. If you create a capture group around it "(.*)" you can see in the resulting capture in column 2.